# mod_rewrite to force ssl in apache24

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am running Apache24 on a FreeBSD 10.1 server. I want to control access to some parts of the website using a mysql database. As authentication is performed using AuthType Basic, I want to force SSL to avoid receiving password in clear text.

The following configuration seams to work, but I a not sure if mod_rewrite operates before or after the authentication.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache24/data/webdav">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    Dav On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthBasicProvider socache dbd
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT passwd FROM webdav_group_v WHERE user = %s"
    AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will work, it will ask for the authorization before the redirect to SSL. Instead you could put the `Auth` directives in a `VirtualHost` block corresponding to the SSL port (443). Also you don't really need mod_rewrite, but a simple `Redirect` directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.domain.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache24/data/webdav"
    Dav On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthBasicProvider socache dbd
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT passwd FROM webdav_group_v WHERE user = %s"
    AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
    Require valid-user
</VirtualHost>
```